# Convert html file to pdf using weasyprint python

Tags: python, html, pdf, weasyprint

I have a lot of HTML file which I want to save as a pdf files in my local

So I am trying weasyprint to convert it but could not do it

can any help me with the code?

```
def pdf_generate():
    try:
        #Replace '56129.html' with the path to your HTML file
        html_file_path = 'farm_management/scripts/56129.html'

        html = HTML(filename=html_file_path)

        pdf_file_path = 'my_pdf_file.pdf'

        pdf_file = html.write_pdf(pdf_file_path)
        with open("my_pdf_file.pdf", 'wb') as f:
            f.write(pdf_file)

        print(f'PDF file has been written to: {pdf_file_path}')

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

and getting this error

```
a bytes-like object is required, not 'NoneType'
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, but I suspect you don't need any of the code in the `with` block.

Comment: Please add the full traceback, not only that one line with the error message. At the moment we don't know where the error occurs.

Comment: I never worked with this library, but If you read the documentation the reason for the error seems pretty clear. `html.write_pdf` saves the file and gives back `None` (in this case). Then you try to write the file again manually, but you provide the returned `None` as the data that should be written. So the comment from @fakedad seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have to at least have a look at the [documentation](https://doc.courtbouillon.org/weasyprint/stable/api_reference.html#weasyprint.HTML)

```
import weasyprint

html = weasyprint.HTML("C:\\test\\file.html")
html.write_pdf(target="C:\\test\\file.pdf")
```